# Add custom image in Views (No field)

Tags: 7, views, entities, media

I have field structure in Views page. And i want add a image every page item. But not want create img field.,

I search this options in my Views, found 'custom text' option but not found a solution.

Is it possible? How? Thank you.

Comment: I think it would depend on what image you wanted to display.  Is it a static image (i.e. the same image on every view)?  Or will this image be different based on the content being viewed?  You can hard code it into a custom text area, create a template file and hard code it there, rewrite the output of a field... lots of different ways depending on what's needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the image in that view's template file.

For views hook suggestions refer to this page http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7

It would be best if you copy the default `views-view-fields.tpl.php` from views module to your theme directory and add the image there.

Answer (score 2):

If the image can be considered data, I'd do as others have said and put it either in the views definition (which you've said you don't want to do), or place the image using the views template.

However, if the image is purely presentation, I'd sooner use CSS to place the image as a background image.